# Ubuntu 22.04 wipes out /etc/resolv.conf symlink on reboot!

Tags: 22.04, resolvconf

I'm trying to transition from an older Debian 10 container to a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 container. When re-installing and configuring everything I'm having a heck of a time with resolvconf.

For some reason, after every reboot something wipes out the following symlink:

/etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

If I run `dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` it will re-create the symlink, but when I reboot then it's gone and back to its previous file.

Both systems are using DHCP, stock setting and configs are identical.

Everything I've googled has mentioned to look for a networkmanager to be installed, which I don't see any installed packages. I've dug through so many config files and systemd scripts but I can't find what's obliterating that symlink! I've compared everything between my Debian and Ubuntu install and I've got nothing.

Comment: Ubuntu now uses Netplan (`https://netplan.io` and `https://netplan.io/examples`) and `systemd` to manage `/etc/resolv.conf`. Read `man systemd-resolved`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was Proxmox that was overwriting the file.

I was able to create a file `/etc/.pve-ignore.resolv.conf` and now the symlink survives reboots.

I've posted on the Proxmox forum as now I'm trying to figure out why it's doing this on one container and not the other. So strange.